# Gstreamer - Hardware accelerated video decoding on Android

Tags: android, video, gstreamer, h.264, hardware-acceleration

I'm receiving on my Android mobile phone a video via RTP/UDP, but I've seen that CPU usage is very high, nearly 100% of one core is being used to decode the video. On high-end devices the video is played almost smoothly, but on middle and low-end devices I barely get 1 frame per second. It's a H.264 video streaming, its resolution is 480x360, at 30 fps.

This is my pipeline:

```
udpsrc port=5004 caps=application/x-rtp,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264
    ! rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true max-dropout-time=500
    ! rtph264depay
    ! video/x-h264,width=480,height=360,framerate=30/1,profile=baseline,stream-format=avc,alignment=au
    ! h264parse
    ! decodebin
    ! videoconvert
    ! autovideosink
```

As far as I've read, the issue here is that by using `decodebin` the CPU is the responsible for decoding the video, which is not good.

So now I'm trying to find a replacement for that element in order to decode the video using hardware acceleration. I've found that I can use an element like `amcviddec-XXXX` where I have to refer to a hardware decoder. A list of available elements should be in the file `/etc/media_codecs.xml` from the device, but I can't figure out which element and how can I insert the valid decoder into my pipeline. These are the contents of that file: http://pastebin.com/9KxHDpE3

I've tried something like `amcviddec-omxgoogleh264decoder` or `amcviddec-omxmarvellvideohwcoda7542decoder` but I always get this error: `GStreamer encountered a general supporting library error`. At least the pipeline is well formed and all elements seem to be understood by Gstreamer.

Error log: http://pastebin.com/raw/H5FDiqTQ