# Gstreamer Android HW accelerated H.264 encoding

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I'm working on a robot that streams two camera streams using `Gstreamer` from a `Jetson Nano` over `UDP` to an Android device.

At this point, I'm taking one of the streams and trying to encode the video to display on an Android device. My Gstreamer pipeline looks like this:

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.239:8554/test ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! amcviddec-omxexynosavcdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false"
```

On the phone I'm using pre-built binaries of Gstreamer and have an implementation very similiar to [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/video.html?gi-language=c).

From `MediaCodecList` Android API, I've managed to find out, that my device has HW acceleration for `OMX.Exynos.avc.dec` so thats why I'm using it in that pipeline.

Now, when I run the app, the native lib gives me this error alongside with some more errors of the "same" type:

```
2022-02-15 12:25:13.570 6377-6377/cz.walle.wallecontroller E/GStreamer+ahc: 0:00:00.095861231 0x7589b71200 ../sys/androidmedia/gst-android-hardware-camera.c:1777:_init_classes Failed to initialize android.hardware.Camera classes: Failed to get static field ID EFFECT_EMBOSS (Ljava/lang/String;): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "EFFECT_EMBOSS" in class "Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;" or its superclasses
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "EFFECT_EMBOSS" in class "Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;" or its superclasses
        at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer.nativeInit(Native Method)
        at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer.init(GStreamer.java:18)
        at cz.walle.wallecontroller.ControlActivity.onCreate(ControlActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8282)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4005)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.ha
2022-02-15 12:25:13.570 6377-6377/cz.walle.wallecontroller E/GStreamer+ahs: 0:00:00.096544154 0x7589b71200 ../sys/androidmedia/gst-android-hardware-sensor.c:596:_init_classes Failed to initialize Android classes: Failed to call Java method: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org/freedesktop/gstreamer/androidmedia/GstAhsCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~cU9DGdEFi5D9pOGi5u1pLw==/cz.walle.wallecontroller-nq-kqx36s-N7ImViW2Lwrw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~cU9DGdEFi5D9pOGi5u1pLw==/cz.walle.wallecontroller-nq-kqx36s-N7ImViW2Lwrw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~cU9DGdEFi5D9pOGi5u1pLw==/cz.walle.wallecontroller-nq-kqx36s-N7ImViW2Lwrw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org/freedesktop/gstreamer/androidmedia/GstAhsCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~cU9DGdEFi5D9pOGi5u1pLw==/cz.walle.wallecontroller-nq-kqx36s-N7ImViW2Lwrw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~cU9DGdEFi5D9pOGi5u1pLw==/cz.walle.wallecontroller-nq-kqx36s-N7ImVi
```

The entire stacktrace is [here](https://gist.github.com/rem821/59b231eecd1604d6cb56728a3017cbbc).

Anyone has experience with this? When I try to use different encoder like `avdec_h264` the stream works, but one CPU core can't keep up with encoding.

Comment: You may use decodebin: `rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.239:8554/test ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! decodebin ! autovideosink` or uridecodebin: `uridecodebin uri=rtsp://192.168.1.239:8554/test ! autovideosink`. These bins would select the decoder according to a rank builtin into plugins that should select the most efficient one available.

Comment: Those work great and definitely using HW acceleration, but as opposed to my PC running my previous pipeline, those on my phone have like 5s delay. How can I absolutely minimise it to get close to ~120ms that I'm having on my PC?

Comment: `latency=0` param on rtspsrc solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see it helped. I've made the answer so that this topic can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use decodebin that would select the decoder according to a rank built into plugins. That should select the most efficient one available for decoding:

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.239:8554/test latency=300 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Note that the optimal latency may not be acheived with the lowest value. It depends on stream-format and network available bandwidth. Just try various values running for quite long duration and see.